# My query duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a query to get a report but when I make my conditions I found 3 columns duplicated with the rest of result.

What I missed ?

the columns  are `A.MailTo,A.Text`, `a.openTIME`,`a.closedtime`

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.FirstName, 
                U.LastName,
                U.LogonID,
                S.NAME Skillset,
                A.MailTo,A.Text,
                a.openTIME,a.closedtime 
FROM CLS.USERS U join CLS.Skillsets S on U.CCMSID =S.CCMSID
                 join CLS.CONTACTS C on S.ID=C.SKILLSET 
                 join CLS.Actions  A on A.agent=C.agent
WHERE a.source=40 
 and cast(a.closedtime as date)= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)-1
```

Comment: What does your data look like (sample data is fine)? What are you expecting to get as output given the sample data? What are you actually seeing with your query and how is that wrong? What are your table structures? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it probably just means you have more than 1 action for those agents.

Comment: Is it MySQL or Oracle? If it isn't "both", please remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can receive duplicate columns is when you call the column more than once with different aliases, however, it sounds like you meant you're returning duplicate rows. If they are all the same information in the duplicates, you can just throw a

```
group by u.logonID
```

making your code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.FirstName, 
            U.LastName,
            U.LogonID,
            S.NAME Skillset,
            A.MailTo,A.Text,
            a.openTIME,a.closedtime 
FROM CLS.USERS U join CLS.Skillsets S on U.CCMSID =S.CCMSID
             join CLS.CONTACTS C on S.ID=C.SKILLSET 
             join CLS.Actions  A on A.agent=C.agent
WHERE a.source=40 
   and cast(a.closedtime as date)= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)-1 
group by u.logonID
```

It should remove any duplicates you may have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have many actions per contact. You can show their count like this (if ID is primary key for Actions):

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT      U.FirstName, 
            U.LastName,
            U.LogonID,
            S.NAME Skillset,
            count(A.ID) agentCount
FROM CLS.USERS U join CLS.Skillsets S on U.CCMSID =S.CCMSID
             join CLS.CONTACTS C on S.ID=C.SKILLSET 
             join CLS.Actions  A on A.agent=C.agent
WHERE a.source=40 
and cast(a.closedtime as date)= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)-1
group by   U.FirstName, 
            U.LastName,
            U.LogonID,
            S.NAME
) order by agentCount desc;
```